# Can all proper sublattices of $\mathbb{Z}^n$ be generated cyclically?

Tags: gr.group-theory, lattices, abelian-groups

Let $\Lambda \subset \mathbb{Z}^n$ be a proper sublattice (so that $\Lambda \ne \mathbb{Z}^n$). We say that $\Lambda$ is cyclically generated if there exists a matrix $M \in \text{GL}_n(\mathbb{Z})$ and an element $\mathbf{u} \in \mathbb{Z}^n$ such that $\Lambda$ is equal the $\mathbb{Z}$-span of $\{\mathbf{u}, M \mathbf{u}, M^2 \mathbf{u}, \cdots \}$. Is it true that all proper sublattices are cyclically generated? If so, how would one prove this, and if not, what's a counterexample?

Comment: @SamHopkins I don't think what you claim is true. For example, take $M = \left(\begin{smallmatrix} 6 & 5 \\ 1 & 1 \end{smallmatrix} \right)$ and $\mathbf{u} = (1,1)^T$. Then $M \mathbf{u} = (11, 2)^T$ which plainly does not have the same length as $\mathbf{u}$.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer is yes, but my solution seems inelegant. Specifically: we can assume WLOG that the sublattice is generated by elements that are multiples $d_i \vec{e}_i$ of the standard basis vectors, and such that $d_1 | d_2 | \dots | d_n$. Then we can choose $M$ to be bidiagonal with $1$ on the diagonal and $\frac{d_{i + 1}}{d_i}$ below the diagonal, and $d_1 \vec{e}_1$ will be cyclic.

Comment: @user44191 why can you make such an assumption? In general one can assume that $\Lambda$ has a basis which forms an upper triangular (or lower triangular) matrix, but not necessarily diagonal. We can only perform row or column operations, not both.

Comment: @StanleyYaoXiao You can make such an assumption because $\Lambda = A \Lambda'$ for some $A \in GL_n(\mathbb{Z})$ and $\Lambda'$ of the form specified; if $M', u'$ are a cyclic pair for $\Lambda'$, then $u := Au', M := A M' A^{-1}$ is a cyclic pair for $\Lambda$. And such an $A$ and $\Lambda'$ are guaranteed by Smith normal form.

Comment: What user44191 sounds right to me. In particular, why can't we perform both row and column operations?

Comment: @WillSawin A lattice can be seen as the column space (or row space, by taking transposes) of some generator matrix. Row operations can change the column space, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1376284/do-row-operations-change-the-column-space-of-a-matrix) for a simple example.

Comment: @WillSawin I am thinking that if you have $n$ column vectors $\mathbf{v}_1, \cdots, \mathbf{v}_n$ say, then taking column operations preserves the lattice spanned by the $\mathbf{v}_j$'s, but row operations do not.

Comment: @StanleyYaoXiao It's worth mentioning that the simple case of $M$ being a suitable permutation matrix ("cyclic rotation operator") leads to the case of cyclic lattices, which are known to not include all lattices. One can generalize the notation of cyclic lattices to [ideal lattices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_lattice), where I believe $M$ is the companion matrix of some polynomial, and again gets a strict subset of all lattices.

Comment: @Mark fascinating! I didn't know the notion of 'ideal lattices' have been developed. If you have more references on them please let me know, perhaps via email if you don't mind.

Comment: If you send $M$ to $g Mg^{-1}$ and $u$ to $gu$ then the matrix $N$ whose columns are $u, Mu, M^2u,\dots, M^{n-1} u$ a becomes $g N$. That gives you the row operations.

Comment: @user44191 I think you should post your comment as an answer...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some standard latticework allows us to write $\Lambda = \text{im}(A)$ for some $n$ by $n$ matrix $A$ (with nonzero determinant). Using Smith normal form, there are some $U, V \in GL_n(\mathbb{Z})$ such that $UAV = D$, where $D$ is a diagonal matrix with diagonal elements $d_1 | d_2 | \dots | d_n$.

Write $\vec{e}_i$ for each of the standard basis vectors. Then let $\vec{u} := U^{-1} d_1 \vec{e}_1$, and let $M := U^{-1}BU$, where $B$ is the bidiagonal matrix with all $1$s on the diagonal, and $\frac{d_{i + 1}}{d_i}$ on the subdiagonal. Note that $det(B) = 1$, and so $B \in GL_n(\mathbb{Z})$; correspondingly, so is $M$. I claim that $(\vec{u}, M)$ is a cyclic pair for $\Lambda$.

Proof: Write $\vec{v}_i := U^{-1} d_i \vec{e}_i$ for each $i$. Note that $\vec{u} = \vec{v}_1$. Then each $\vec{v}_i \in \text{im}(U^{-1}D) = \text{im}(U^{-1}DV^{-1}) = \text{im}(M) = \Lambda$; further, it's not hard to see that they generate $\Lambda$ (by the same reasoning taken backwards).

We can check that $M \vec{v}_i = U^{-1}BU U^{-1} d_i \vec{e}_i = U^{-1} B d_i \vec{e}_i = U^{-1} (d_i \vec{e}_i + d_{i + 1} \vec{e}_{i + 1}) = \vec{v}_i + \vec{v}_{i + 1}$ for $1 \leq i < n$. Noting the base case that $\vec{v}_1 = \vec{u}$, we can use induction to see that $\vec{v}_{i + 1} = M \vec{v}_i - \vec{v}_i \in \text{span}(\{M^j \vec{u}\}_{j = 0}^i)$. As the $\{\vec{v}_i\}$ are a generating set, $\text{span}(\{M^j \vec{u}\}_{j = 0}^{n - 1}) = \Lambda$, and we are done.